# How to specify a range of array elements

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on an application that fills in a number of arrays. But being originally a VB6 application, it doesn't use element zero of any of them. This stops things like

```
my_array.Min
```

from working properly. I have no plans to tamper with the innards of the application, but it would be very convenient if I could specify a range of array elements in this sort of statement; something like

```
my_array(1:100).Min
```

Does such a construction exist, and if so, what is it?

Comment: What is `Min`? Can you show code that compiles in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately .NET doesn’t have a convenient array slice construct<sup>1</sup> (although you can use Linq to approximate it) but you’re solving the wrong X in an XY problem here.

The real solution is not to use 1-based arrays. *Do* change the innards of your application.

Incidentally, the default base for arrays in VB6 was *also* zero. You explicitly needed to specify `Option Base 1` for 1-based arrays.

---

<sup>1</sup> There’s [`ArraySegment(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) but before .NET 4.5 this structure was completely broken since it didn’t implement the `IList(T)` interface and was thus unusable. It does implement that now, but it’s too late – nobody is using the class.

Comment: +1. I guess Brian is referring to code written by devs who were unaware of VB6's default behaviour, e.g. writing `Dim a(5)` and only accessing elements 1-5. This is a common problem. :-(

Comment: Thanks for that. Sigh. All I wanted to do was chop the unused bottom half off a graph, and now the worms are out of the can and wriggling everywhere. I suppose a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do...